# War on candies (or on other threats to modern, affluent people)

Tags: internal-consistency, near-future, food, law, health

I need some societal ills/threats that nowadays are being treated as mostly neglected, but in a near future one could imagine a proper moral panic and attempts to eradicate it (regulate, properly supervise, keep away from minors, etc.) for common good. The threats would have to be more or less real (at least conflicting studies).

Imagine, that with enthusiasm similar to war on drugs one would try to fight with junk food. After all technically speaking such food is clearly harmful, just one may feel a bit weird with prisons filled with people who were caught while selling fried bacon.

OK, so what are possible targets of future moral panics of threats that are already present nowadays (so no nanomachines):

-junk food (salt, simple sugars, saturated fat) - damn unhealthy

-peanuts (some people have life threatening allergies to that)

-artificial fertilizers (an material for making explosives)

-drones (seem to have huge potential for terrorism /assassination, that’s something that I’d actually expect to be heavily regulated sooner or later in RL)

-computer games/internet (addiction potential)

-risky sports

Do I miss some more threats with moral panic potential?

A perfect answer would include a list of minor but real risks that has some scientific reasons, that nowadays are not being taken too seriously as public threat that requires proper crusade. In case of any cultural ambiguity threats should apply especially to the Western civilization.

Comment: Climate change https://newrepublic.com/article/135684/declare-war-climate-change-mobilize-wwii

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- Alcohol and [Tobacco](http://www.nber.org/papers/w18326.pdf)
- [Sugar](http://www.bbc.com/news/health-37620087)
- Mobile Phone addiction
- TV, movies and [video games](http://abcnews.go.com/US/story?id=95401&page=1) glorifying violence
- [Fossil Fueled Vehicles](http://www.zevfacts.com/zev-mandate.html)
- [Eating Meat](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2016/may/25/un-expert-calls-for-tax-on-meat-production)
- Capitalism and Greed
- Owning Pets
- [Spanking Children](http://thefreethoughtproject.com/mom-arrested-spanking/)
- [Alternative Medicines](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/health/article-3316720/Ban-homeopathy-NHS-no-evidence-works-ministers-say.html)
- Creationism
- Being Unfit or overweight
- Incarceration instead of rehabilitation
- [Homophobia](http://www.adfmedia.org/News/PRDetail/8608), Xenophobia

Comment: instant +1 for "eating meat", it's actually such a huge concern that may become agressively handled in certain cases.

Comment: Edited for links because Big Brother is way ahead of @Innovine.

Answer (score 3):

The war on online communities.

Why do people feel the need to associate and find like-minded people if not for nefarious purposes? Especially when culture is generously dispensed by the State and well-informed corporations in nice digestible bits designed for the enjoyment of all.

Let's root them out!

Comment: In one of my "proto-world-concepts" I tried to make a cyberpunk-ish approach on it, but a discussion on Reddit made me realize that it's way too vague and is rooted so deeply and widely in our society that would make no sense for such a war, neither any way of measuring success. If anyone's interested, I may dig up to find the exact discussion.

Comment: An online community, such as this one?.... BLASPHEMY! :O

Comment: Not a half bad idea. I mean for every Worldbuilding Stack Exchange there is a dozen Stormfront's. I didn't link it for a reason, don't google that.

Answer (score 3):

Headphones and personal music players.

- They damage your hearing over the long term.
- They are anti-social.
- They cause accidents.

Answer (score 1):

Certain modern cartoons, including but not limited to anime.

The effect of these on the development of children's mentality is very controversial in several aspects, like:

- perception of reality, both in basic and society level.
- definition and range of **values**, in the sense of society.
- the way they approach problems to solve them.

As a most notable example, several of these cartoons propagate the view that violence is a good solution of problems **and** is a good way of measuring one's position in the society's hierarchy ranking.

*Note: I do like anime and several modern western cartoons as well, I just tried to make an approach for the issue in the question.*